# How to dynamically resize a vega chart in react to fit in a css grid

Tags: css, reactjs, vega

My initial problem :

I am using `react-vega` and placing a few vega charts within a css grid.  I would like to dynamically resize the charts as the browser window gets narrower (ideally to a `min-width`) currently if i shrink the width the charts start to overlap which just looks horrible.  I have found a few references to `containerSize()` but haven't found any good examples of how to implement it. What is the best option with vega to do this? 
[posted to the vega slack channel]

after some back and forth with "Kanit Wongsuphasawat" and "Rob Wollen" there appears to not be a good way to do this incorporated into vega or vega-react right now and I have tried the below method but still have a problem.

My approach :

I have tried using `react-measure` [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-measure) and built a react component below:

```
import Measure from 'react-measure';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NetworkUpDownChart from './vega-network-updown-chart';
import Vega from 'react-vega';

export default class ItemToMeasure extends Component {
  state = {
    dimensions: {
      width: -1,
      height: -1,
    },
  }

  data = {
   table: [
    {"x": 0, "y": 28, "c":0}, {"x": 0, "y": -55, "c":1}
     ...
   ]
 };

spec = {
"$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v4.json",
"width": 900,
"height": 200,
"padding": 5,
    "autosize": {
  "type": "pad",
  "resize": true,
},
"data": [
  {
    "name": "table",
    // data will be passed in via props
    "transform": [
      {
        "type": "stack",
        "groupby": ["x"],
        "sort": {"field": "c"},
        "field": "y"
      }
    ]
  }
],

"scales": [
  {
    "name": "x",
    "type": "point",
    "range": "width",
    "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "x"}
  },
  {
    "name": "y",
    "type": "linear",
    "range": "height",
    "nice": true, "zero": true,
    "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "y1"}
  },
  {
    "name": "color",
    "type": "ordinal",
    "range": "category",
    "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "c"}
  }
],

"axes": [
  {"orient": "bottom", "scale": "x", "zindex": 1},
  {"orient": "left", "scale": "y", "zindex": 1}
],

"marks": [
  {
    "type": "group",
    "from": {
      "facet": {
        "name": "series",
        "data": "table",
        "groupby": "c"
      }
    },
    "marks": [
      {
        "type": "area",
        "from": {"data": "series"},
        "encode": {
          "enter": {
            "interpolate": {"value": "monotone"},
            "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "x"},
            "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "y0"},
            "y2": {"scale": "y", "field": "y1"},
            "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "c"}
          },
          "update": {
            "fillOpacity": {"value": 1}
          },
          "hover": {
            "fillOpacity": {"value": 0.5}
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
}

render() {
  const { width, height } = this.state.dimensions
// const className = classNames(width < 400 && 'small-width-modifier')

return (
  <Measure
    bounds
    onResize={contentRect => {
      this.setState({ dimensions: contentRect.bounds })
    }}
  >
    {({ measureRef }) => (
       <div ref={measureRef}>
         {width < 250 && (
             <Vega width={width} spec={this.spec} data={this.data}/>,
        <NetworkUpDownChart width={width} data={this.data}> . </NetworkUpDownChart>)}
       <pre>{measureRef}</pre> 
       </div>
    )}
  </Measure>
  )
 }
}
```

When i use the component it "dynamically resizes the graph" just not when the browser window is resized. Instead it just does it constantly growing from 0 -> 250 (this is the number i wrote down in the component logic as the max) then resetting. If i remove the conditional logic there it just continues to grow forever.

[image: auto growing chart]

Ideally i would like to fix this so that it does not continually grow and will shrink when i resize the browser but I would appreciate any help or alternative solutions to this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have managed to figure this out.

When i Encase the above component in the css grid with this styling:

```
.parent-container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    '. el1 . el2 .';
  grid-template-columns: 10% 30% 20% 30% 10%;
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
}
```

I needed to add an extra div in the component since the className was not being applied to the `<Measure>` block, see below for an updated return. Note I am now able to remove the extra binding logic on size for the Vega chart:

```
return (   
    <div className="el2">
        <Measure
            bounds
            onResize={contentRect => {
            this.setState({ dimensions: contentRect.bounds })
            }}
        >
            {({ measureRef }) => (
            <div  ref={measureRef}>
                <NetworkUpDownChart width={width} data={this.data}></NetworkUpDownChart>
            </div>
            )}
        </Measure>

    </div>
 )
}
```